# How to insert HTML Editor in Grid?

Tags: asp.net, html, datagrid, telerik, html-editor

Hello, I am using 'Trial Of Tekerik Controls', I am building the Grid. Now, I want to insert HTML Edit control in the Grid when I press 'Edit' and then select row ShortDescription. I want HTML control to open, so that I can edit all information inside.

[image]

You can see here the example.

Here is my code

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" ShowGroupPanel="True" GridLines="None" DataSourceID="DataSource1" AllowFiltering="False" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowAutomaticInserts="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="True" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True" CellSpacing="0">
                <MasterTableView GroupLoadMode="client" ShowGroupFooter="False" GroupsDefaultExpanded="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter ID column" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" UniqueName="ID">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="LoadCategory" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter LoadCategory column" HeaderText="LoadCategory" SortExpression="LoadCategory" UniqueName="LoadCategory">
                        </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProductCategory" FilterControlAltText="Filter ProductCategory column" HeaderText="ProductCategory" SortExpression="ProductCategory" UniqueName="ProductCategory">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ShortDescription" FilterControlAltText="Filter ShortDescription column" HeaderText="ShortDescription" SortExpression="ShortDescription" UniqueName="ShortDescription">

                          <%-- This is the row --%>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NumberOfItems" DataType="System.Int16" FilterControlAltText="Filter NumberOfItems column" HeaderText="NumberOfItems" SortExpression="NumberOfItems" UniqueName="NumberOfItems">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CategoryTitle" FilterControlAltText="Filter CategoryTitle column" HeaderText="CategoryTitle" SortExpression="CategoryTitle" UniqueName="CategoryTitle">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SeoTitle" FilterControlAltText="Filter SeoTitle column" HeaderText="SeoTitle" SortExpression="SeoTitle" UniqueName="SeoTitle">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SeoDescription" FilterControlAltText="Filter SeoDescription column" HeaderText="SeoDescription" SortExpression="SeoDescription" UniqueName="SeoDescription">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
                <ClientSettings AllowDragToGroup="True">
                </ClientSettings>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Any ideas how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution you just need to change

```
  <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ShortDescription" FilterControlAltText="Filter ShortDescription column" HeaderText="ShortDescription" SortExpression="ShortDescription" UniqueName="ShortDescription">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

to `GridHTMLEditorColumn`

```
 <telerik:GridHTMLEditorColumn DataField="ShortDescription" FilterControlAltText="Filter ShortDescription column" HeaderText="ShortDescription" SortExpression="ShortDescription" UniqueName="ShortDescription">
                        </telerik:GridHTMLEditorColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UserControlEditForm`

```
    <EditFormSettings UserControlName="yourUserControl.ascx" EditFormType="WebUserControl">
            <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
            </EditColumn>
    </EditFormSettings>
```

In `yourUserControl.ascx` , you can add telerik RadEditor or some other html editor .

This is how to get value from Grid to userControl,

```
  object _fieldValue = DataBinder.Eval(DataItem, "YourDataField");
        if ((_fieldValue != DBNull.Value) && (_fieldValue != null))
        {
            yourHtmlEditor.Text = _fieldValue .ToString();

        }
```

and this is how to get value from userControl to your Main Grid,

```
  UserControl usercontrol = (UserControl)e.Item.FindControl(GridEditFormItem.EditFormUserControlID);
  string _value= (usercontrol.FindControl("yourHtmlEditor") as typeOfyourEditor).Text;
```

You can see the  [reference1](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/usercontroleditform/defaultcs.aspx&ei=99f4UY2IHMW_kQWzjoC4Cw&usg=AFQjCNEm2aGTBSgS7bQ0nftBQrSlWEc6JQ&sig2=TiGHQFziISvnCr8lc4AvBw&bvm=bv.49967636,d.dGI&cad=rja) , [reference2](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/usercontrol-as-editform-for-radgrid.aspx) !

**or**

Without using `userControlEditForm` , you can use `editFormTemplate`

```
 <EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template">
            <FormTemplate>
```

See [demo1](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/templateformupdate/defaultcs.aspx&ei=g9v4UeuoGMf_lAXihoHQAg&usg=AFQjCNHRPIlLOMLePQEwHhfca6MurRn6Bw&sig2=IYUzq7_CNLbfRrf_EY-SGQ&bvm=bv.49967636,d.dGI&cad=rja) and [demo2](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/telerik-radgrid-edit-form-template.aspx&ei=g9v4UeuoGMf_lAXihoHQAg&usg=AFQjCNGQ7zvtubpeeIcUs_stDS8DHOU55Q&sig2=x6MUhQaaXFaVudjbLxx1Ow&bvm=bv.49967636,d.dGI&cad=rja) !

Good Luck :)